# PrimeFaces Dialog not positioning right and some options make it stop working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

I've already search trhough other posts for a solution to my problem with no luck, so im posting here. My problem is that primefaces dialog is not showing where it should, at the center of the page, at rare times it does(dont understand why), it works fine but its showing at the left top corner, and if i change the option "draggable" from false to true, the dialog stops working... i call the dialog from a managed bean.

this is the code:

form where i call it:

```
<h:form style="margin-top: 2%;">
    <p:commandButton value="Create Ticket" icon="ui-icon-extlink" action="#    {ticketBean.viewCreateCustomized}"/>
</h:form>
```

ManagedBean that contains the dialog method:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TicketBean implements Serializable {

public void viewTicketCustomized() {
    Map<String,Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    options.put("modal", true);
    options.put("draggable", false);
    options.put("resizable", false);
    options.put("contentHeight", 320);

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("createticket", options, null);
}
```

UPDATE: this is the view that the dialog shows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
<h:outputScript name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" library="primefaces"/>
<title>Create New Account</title>
<link href="#{request.contextPath}/css/simple.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-widget {
        font-size: 110%;
    }
</style>
</h:head>
<f:view>
<center><h:form style="margin-top: 2%;">
        <p:growl id="msg" showDetail="true"/>
    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
        <f:facet name="header">Create New Ticket</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="Description:" />
        <p:inputTextarea value="#{ticketBean.description}"/>
        <h:outputText value="Note:" />
        <p:inputTextarea value="#{ticketBean.note}"/>
        <f:facet name="footer"><p:commandButton value="Create Ticket" action="#    {ticketBean.createTicket}" update="msg"/></f:facet>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form></center>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Comment: Is opening a dialog (`<p:dialog>`) in this way (writing Java Code in the bean) absolutely necessary in your application?

Comment: @Tiny i use it in the ManagedBean so it can use the navigation rule instead of putting the link directly into the view. Now, i think i had to put the content of the view that the dialog is showing, sorry bout that, im gonna edit it right now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what browser you are using or if your problem is related to the browser at all. But I tried your code and did not succeed to show the dialog. However, when I changed it to the following it worked:

```
<h:form style="margin-top: 2%;">
    <p:commandButton value="Create Ticket" icon="ui-icon-extlink" onclick="test.show();"/>
    <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="test" draggable="true" resizable="false" contentHeight="320">
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

I'm not sure if there is a reason you have to show the dialog from the managed bean, but if you do, then instead of "onclick.show()" you can do the following:

```
<h:form style="margin-top: 2%;">
    <p:commandButton value="Create Ticket" icon="ui-icon-extlink" action="#{ticketBean.viewTicketCustomized()}"/>
    <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="test" draggable="true" resizable="false" contentHeight="320">
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

and in your managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TicketBean implements Serializable {

public void viewTicketCustomized() {
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.execute("test.show();");
}
```

Comment: as i commented to @Tiny, i use it in the ManagedBean because of the navigation, so i wouldnt have to put the link directly on the view.

And about your solution, i dont want to put the form in the same view, for clarity purposes. I updated my question with the code of the form that the dialog shows, wich i didnt include earlier. Thanks.